# Javascript data overwritten by jinja rendered data

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, django, jinja2

I'm trying to implement like-unlike functionality in a blog project. Initially the page shows data using Jinja2 template variable in html. When the user clicks the 'LIKE' link  it calls a javascript function where the fetch function updates data on the back-end and gets the latest count of likes and like status and updates that data in html.

**Issue:** The JavaScript is working fine, I can see that after the onClick function is executed, the like count increases and the value of anchor tag changes from 'Like' to 'Unlike'. But soon after it is set to unlike, it is overwritten by jinja data to 'like'. I'm not sure what I'm missing here, any help is very much appreciated.

HTML code:

````
```<div class="media-body">
        <div id="post{{post.id}}">
        <h4><a class="article-title" href="{% url 'getProfile' post.get_userId %}">{{ post.user.username }}</a></h4>
        <div id='existing-post'>
        <p class="article-content">{{ post.content }}</p>
        <div class="article-metadata">
            <small class="text-muted">{{ post.date_posted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>  
            <a href="">edit</a>  
            <input type="hidden" class="hidden" id="userId" value={{user.id}}>           
          </div>
          <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true" style="color: red;"></i><span id="countEle"> {{ post.get_likes_count }}</span>
          <a  href="" class="post{{post.id}}" onclick=changeLikes(this.className) > {% if user in post.get_likes %} Unlike {% else %} Like {% endif%}</a>
        </div>
      </div>```
````

JavaScript code:

```
function changeLikes(clickedId){
    divEle=document.getElementById(clickedId);
    likedBy= document.getElementById('userId').value;
    // id_value=this.id
    
    var likedBy =divEle.querySelector('#userId').value;

    postId=clickedId.substring(4)
    
    fetch('/changeLikes', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'postId': postId,
            'likedBy': likedBy
        })
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
          // Print result
          console.log(result);
          divEle.querySelector('#countEle').textContent=result.likesCount;
          divEle.getElementsByClassName(clickedId)[0].textContent=result.likedStatus;
          
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this could be one problem:
are you importing the javascript function into your HTML?
another issue:
replace:

```
onclick=changeLikes(this.className)
```

with:

```
onclick="changeLikes(this.className)"
```

or:

````
```+changeLikes("post{{post.id}}")+```
````

I recommend changing the classname.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried both the ways which you suggested. but nothing worked. The issue still exists.

Comment: Regarding the class name, The posts are looped in a for loop and by adding 'post'+postId I'm trying to generate unique classnames.  If you see any other ways to generate unique classname please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by replacing anchor tag with span tag. Anchor tag was refreshing the page again with the old data onclick, overwriting the javascript data.